# Why am I getting "Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary" warning with this setup?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, raid

On a fresh install of Proxmox 8.1, fdisk -l is warning "Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary". This is unexpected to me, because the start of the partition is 2099200, which is divisible by 8 (4096/512).

I am concerned this will affect performance and SSD longevity.

**System Info**:

OS: Proxmox 8.1 (Debian 12.5)

Hardware: MegaRAID 12GSAS/PCIe Secure SAS39xx, 4 disks in RAID 5

**lshw -class disk -class storage**

```
      *-raid
           description: RAID bus controller
           product: MegaRAID 12GSAS/PCIe Secure SAS39xx
           vendor: Broadcom / LSI
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:81:00.0
           logical name: scsi0
           logical name: /dev/fb0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: raid pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom fb
           configuration: depth=32 driver=megaraid_sas latency=0 mode=1024x768 visual=truecolor xres=1024 yres=768
           resources: iomemory:2000-1fff iomemory:2000-1fff irq:51 memory:20020f00000-20020ffffff memory:20020e00000-20020efffff memory:f2100000-f21fffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f2000000-f20fffff
         *-disk
              description: SCSI Disk
              product: MR9560-8i
              vendor: BROADCOM
              physical id: 3.6f.0
              bus info: scsi@0:3.111.0
              logical name: /dev/sda
              version: 5.27
              serial: 00cd0054e9b972052d000a6910b26200
              size: 2681GiB (2878GB)
              capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
              configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=efea2081-a6ca-4151-ae8b-d5cc971ce290 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

**fdisk -x**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2.62 TiB, 2878970265600 bytes, 5622988800 sectors
Disk model: MR9560-8i
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EFEA2081-A6CA-4151-AE8B-D5CC971CE290
First usable LBA: 34
Last usable LBA: 5622988766
Alternative LBA: 5622988799
Partition entries starting LBA: 2
Allocated partition entries: 128
Partition entries ending LBA: 33

Device       Start        End    Sectors Type-UUID                            UUID                                 Name Attrs
/dev/sda1       34       2047       2014 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 7E31886C-4D4F-43A7-8F53-81BA700F4394
/dev/sda2     2048    2099199    2097152 C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B 40656EBB-ABAE-4A26-BBA4-3D18CDAD8D80
/dev/sda3  2099200 5622988766 5620889567 E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928 33753DAF-6729-4730-8237-318CED86E220

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/mapper/pve-swap: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/pve-root: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 59.99 GiB, 64416120832 bytes, 125812736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8b7a7123

Device                                  Boot     Start       End   Sectors Id Type Start-C/H/S  End-C/H/S Attrs
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part1 *         2048   1953791   1951744 83 Linu       4/4/1 1023/254/2    80
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part2        1953792   3907583   1953792 82 Linu  1023/254/2 1023/254/2
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part3        3909630 602861567 598951938  5 Exte  1023/254/2 1023/254/2
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part5        3909632 101564415  97654784 83 Linu  1023/254/2 1023/254/2
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part6      101566464 103518207   1951744 83 Linu  1023/254/2 1023/254/2
/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0-part7      103520256 602861567 499341312 83 Linu  1023/254/2 1023/254/2

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: You mentioned fdisk -l, but you don't show the output of fdisk -l, but the output of fdisk -x. That  shows partition 1 not starting on a physical boundary (as expected). Are you sure your fdisk -l said "partition 3" ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary` pertains to the device `/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0`, not `/dev/sda` as your statement that `2099200` is the start of the partition seems to suggest.

And indeed, for partition 3 of `/dev/mapper/pve-vm--1001--disk--0` the start sector is not wholly divisible by 512 (`3909630/512=7635.99609375`).

For disk `/dev/sda` you get the same error about partition 1, which is also not aligned on a sector boundary.

Comment: "the start sector is not wholly divisible by 512" – Where did the number 512 come from? Why not 8?

Comment: fdisk output says the logical sector size is 512 bytes: `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes`. The start sector isn’t divisible by 8 either btw.

Comment: But 3909630 is the offset measured in logical sectors. The offset in *bytes* will be divisible by 512, there is no other way. In this case it won't be divisible by 4096, this is what matters. If we don't want to do the math in bytes, if we do want to do the math in logical sectors, then the factor to check is 8 (=4096/512).

Comment: Thanks folks, I understand now.